# Programmatic access to metatag module fields

Tags: 8

I am wondering how to programmatically access `metatag` module data.  For example, my node has an entry for metatag description, and I see in the generated page the meta description tag, which is great.  However, it's not clear how I can access this programmatically.

Right now, I am trying the following:

```
$metatag_manager = \Drupal::service('metatag.manager');
$tags = $metatag_manager->tagsFromEntityWithDefaults($node);
$elements = $metatag_manager->generateRawElements($tags, $node);
```

Inspecting the data, I see that `$tags` includes a `'description'` entry, but `$elements` does not.  Is there a better way of accessing this data?

The `metatag` module includes [documentation for programmatically setting data](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/metatag/howto-programmatically-assign-meta-tags-to-an-entity), but unfortunately does not mention accessing the data.

Edit: Alas, it seems I was inspecting the wrong node -- one with the same title as a node with metadata entries.  Working now with the correct node, it seems all I need to use is:

```
$metatag_manager = \Drupal::service('metatag.manager');
$tags = $metatag_manager->tagsFromEntity($node);
```

Which returns an array with a `description` key and the description value entered for that node.

Answer (score 1):

If you have node object loaded, you can access the meta tags as below:

```
$metaTags = $node->get('field_meta_tags')->value;
if (!empty($metaTags)) {
      $metaTagsArr = unserialize($metaTags);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($metaTagsArr);
echo "</pre>";
}
```